# Why does Koin throw "Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException" in my KMM app?

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, koin, kmm

Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.KoinInstanceHolder from other thread

I have already checked that I am calling InitKoin() on the main thread, and only once, in `onApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I don't think I am doing it from another thread, but I am using Compose UI. The call is to a repository and I'm sure I'm making the error there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my GET call from my repo was using `@withRepoContext{ .. }`. Oops!